# change a value from specific row of a table

Tags: jquery

I want to change specific row in my table, but such has some another `<span>`. I want to change the value in the first span.

My code is like below:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <th>Book_ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A001</td>
    <td>my book</td>
    <td>10000</th>
    <td>
            <span>3</span>
            <span><a>delete</a></span>
            <span>
              <a href=# title="plus_qty"><img src="quantity_up.gif"></a>
            </span>
            <span>
              <a href=# title="minus_qty"><img src="quantity_down.gif"></a>
            </span>
    </td>
    <td>30000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Without deleting `<span title="plus_qty">`, and `<span title="minus_qty">` or without `<span>` in `<td>` I can get and update a qty value. This my code without deleting the elements:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <th>Book_ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A001</td>
    <td>my book</td>
    <td>10000</th>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>30000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code:

```
var row = $('#mytable').find('td');
for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){
   if(row.eq(i).text() == 'A0001'){
       row.eq(i+3).text(parseInt(row.eq(i+3).text())+1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var row = $('#mytable').find('td');
for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){
   if(row.eq(i).text() == 'A0001'){
       ch = row.eq(i+3).children(':first-child');
       ch.text(parseInt(ch.text())+1);
   }
}
```

Take care with a possible typo, in your html code you have `<td>A001</td>` but in your javascript you search for `A0001` which is a different value, after fixing that myself my above code works.